# СSS маскирование через svg маску

Tags: css, svg, mask, css-mask

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так делаю с `svg` маской что оно не дает результат такой как на картинке ?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hero_item {
  position: relative;
}

.hero_picture {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
  max-height: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero_name {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.hero_position {
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.hero_picture img {
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(#mask);
  mask-image: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 276 381" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                    <mask id="mask"  x="0" y="0" width="276" height="381">
                        <path d="M275.056 15.2578C275.056 6.97355 268.34 0.257812 260.056 0.257812H151.467L138.001 23.5179L124.534 0.257812H15.9455C7.66124 0.257812 0.945496 6.97354 0.945496 15.2578V177.183L24.2698 190.612L0.945496 204.042V365.967C0.945496 374.251 7.66122 380.967 15.9455 380.967H124.534L138.001 357.707L151.467 380.967H260.056C268.34 380.967 275.056 374.251 275.056 365.967V204.042L251.731 190.612L275.056 177.183V15.2578Z" fill="white"/>
                    </mask>
                </defs>
            </svg>


<div class="hero_item">
  <div class="hero_picture" style="background: linear-gradient( #FFDD22 50%, #383030 51%)">
    <img width="276" height="381" src="https://i.ibb.co/frKL9TM/1.jpg" alt="1">
  </div>
  <a class="hero_name" href="#">John Doe</a>
  <p class="hero_position">Managing Partner</p>
</div>
```

[image: man]

Не могу понять, что не так с маской. Делал по примеру из [этого](https://web.dev/i18n/ru/css-masking/) описания.
Вот то что из Figma удалось забрать

```
<svg width="276" height="381" viewBox="0 0 276 381" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<mask id="mask0_85_1033" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="276" height="381">
<path d="M275.056 15.2578C275.056 6.97355 268.34 0.257812 260.056 0.257812H151.467L138 23.5179L124.534 0.257812H15.9455C7.66121 0.257812 0.945465 6.97354 0.945465 15.2578V177.183L24.2697 190.612L0.945465 204.042V365.967C0.945465 374.251 7.66119 380.967 15.9455 380.967H124.534L138 357.707L151.467 380.967H260.056C268.34 380.967 275.056 374.251 275.056 365.967V204.042L251.731 190.612L275.056 177.183V15.2578Z" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0_85_1033)">
<rect x="-4.03821" y="-24.5898" width="284.078" height="428.422" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
</g>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0_85_1033" transform="matrix(0.00150812 0 0 0.001 -0.254058 0)"/>
</pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Написано такой подход поддерживается только в Firefox.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image Та вроде бы уже всё хорошо с поддержкой. Просто я как-то не правильно применяю. Только не пойму что не так

Comment: Ну такой пример не работает, там же есть ниже пример где внутри svg вставляется <image>,попробуй может получится. Вот другим способом может подойдет https://jsfiddle.net/Diias/nosfxcd0/2/